# Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - aws.yml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-ebs

site deployed in aws elastic beantalk

aws.yml

```
 production:
  access_key_id: 123333231331....
  secret_access_key: 12212dddddd........
```

production.rb

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :preserve_files => true,
  :s3_credentials => 'aws.yml',
  :s3_region => 'ap-south-1',
  :s3_host_name => 's3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com',
  :bucket => 'xxxxxx'
}
```

I also give public access permissions in s3 bucket.

```
anyone: read write
```

gem...

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.10', '>= 2.10.85'
```

aws.yml folder within config folder -- config/aws.yml

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application is not finding your S3 credentials file.  In your `production.rb`, try giving it the full path to the file:

```
:s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml"
```